# How to get request's path pattern in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way through which one can get the request path *pattern* in the Interceptor layer?

For example:

There's a API whose path is defined as: `/cat/{catid}/summary`

In the Spring integration's interceptor layer the message object provides 
`message.getHeaders().get("http_requestUrl")` which rightly contains the full path with actual value, like `/cat/123455/summary`

Since there are multiple paths in the project, I can't use regrex. How do I get `/cat/{catid}/summary`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the attributes from the request in this way.

```
final Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

pathVariables should contain all the necessary information you need.

Comment: I don't have the request object. I have a Message object, I tried to look for any attribute member in it's class but there isn't. Any idea on how to get the same from the Message object? `org.springframework.messaging.Message`

Comment: Sorry have tried digging around in the message documentation but cant find anything how to access path params. Only how to access query params with help of message.getPayload().